# Insert some characters in a specific place with a regex

Tags: r, regex

I have a string of the following form:

```
text <- "\\usage{afunction(arg = list())anotherfunction()}\\somethingelse{}"
```

I would like to insert `\\n` between `afunction()` and `anotherfunction()`. Expected output:

```
"\\usage{afunction(arg = list()) \\n anotherfunction()}\\somethingelse{}"
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
text <- "\\usage{afunction(arg = list())anotherfunction()}\\somethingelse{}"

pattern <- "(?<=usage\\{)[^\\}]+"

temp <- regmatches(text, gregexpr(pattern, text, perl = TRUE)) 

gsub("\\)", ") \\\\n ", temp, perl = TRUE)
```

which gives

```
"afunction(arg = list() \\n ) \\n anotherfunction() \\n "
```

The problems are that there is `\\n` just after `list()`, and that the rest of the original expression is gone.

How can I do that? (I would prefer a solution in base R)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there will always be no space between the close parentheses and the beginning of a new function (starting with an upper- or lower-case letter), you could use this. This also assumes that you will always want to insert a newline when there is a close parentheses immediately followed by a letter.

```
text <- "\\usage{afunction(arg = list())anotherfunction()}\\somethingelse{}"

gsub("(\\))([A-Za-z])", "\\1 \\\\n \\2", text)
# [1] "\\usage{afunction(arg = list()) \\n anotherfunction()}\\somethingelse{}"
```

Answer (score 2):

If there are no arbitrary string variables or comments in between, you can use a recursion-based pattern like

```r
usage\{\w+(\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\))\K
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VGAfHy/1). Details:

- `usage\{` - a `usage{` string
- `\w+` - one or more word chars
- `(\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\))` - Group 1: a string between parentheses that may contain nested paired parentheses
- `\K` - a match reset operator.

See [the R demo](https://ideone.com/nT8Vsa):

```r
text <- "\\usage{afunction(arg = list())anotherfunction()}\\somethingelse{}"
pattern <- "usage\\{\\w+(\\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\\))\\K"
gsub( pattern, " \\\\n ", text, perl=TRUE ) 
# => [1] "\\usage{afunction(arg = list()) \\n anotherfunction()}\\somethingelse{}"
```

Comment: Very nice with the recursion ++